# How to sync files from local blobstorage to Google Cloud Storage and vica versa?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a Django application deployed in Google App Engine. I'm using the Google Cloud Storage service to store my media files. Mainly images that are belong to some content in my website.

Now it's all looking good and everything is working but this thing really bothers me.

Is there any way to sync your bucket's files to the local blobstorage and upload them back to GCS after you finished with development?

Comment: I think you could use the remote api for that https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi. I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish though. Synchronization of user content to the dev server may work as long as your application is small but it's not feasible for grown applications. Since the File API was deprecated I'm also not sure if you could reuse blob ids.

Comment: Thanks @konqi ! So the proper way is to separate content management and development? The only reason I ask this because there could be cases when I develop updates to my app and I may also want to create new pages or refresh existing ones that are contains non-static files.

Comment: Don't know if there is a proper way. I usually have a couple of datasets in my devserver with which i test locally. Then i push to a staging project in app engine that has more data and finally update the live environment. There is no point in testing against all your data. You just have to test some of the border cases to make sure your application / update works. Otherwise if you would test with all your live data it's quite possible that you'll overlook issues because there is just too much content to look at.